# Why does setMainQmlFile work and setSource fails for the same path?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Why does setMainQmlFile work and setSource fails for the same path?

```
QmlApplicationViewer viewer;
viewer.setOrientation(QmlApplicationViewer::ScreenOrientationAuto);

//viewer.setMainQmlFile(QLatin1String("qml/exQml02/main.qml")); // <-- works
viewer.setSource(QUrl("qrc:qml/exQml02/main.qml")); // <--- fails: qrc:qml/exQml02/main.qml: File not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fails because it is not the same path. The first path is a normal path in your filesystem. There your main.qml exists. The second is a path in the Qt resource system. Looks like you made a mistake when you tried to embed your main.qml into your binary. You did try to embed your main.qml?